# Low Level Issue- Battery issue

Tags: battery, macbook-pro

I have installed Xubunto instead of Machintosh on my MacBook Pro machine, when i close the screen the apple lamp on the back of my laptop doesn't goes off, and the laptop runs out of power. how can i control this back lamp to be on or off ??, is there away to disable it from my Linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default on my Xubuntu installation on Mac OS X closing the lid does not do anything.  What you need to do is open the Whisker menu (mouse icon) and click the settings button in top right.  Then go to Power Manager and set what you want Xubuntu to do when the laptop lid is closed on battery and on AC (you probably want it to suspend to save battery). This is assuming you are running Xubuntu 14.04, if not the Power Manager may be in a different location.

Just as a side note: On my MacBook Pro 9,2 it cannot resume from suspend after it was closed and the display won't turn on.  I heard it was a bug in Xubuntu 14.04, so until the bug is resolved make sure to manually hit suspend from the power button in the whisker menu before closing the lid.  Then when you open it hit a key and it will resume normally hopefully like on my Mac.